# Android Studio uploaded picture to own server via http : picture has only 0 bytes

Tags: java, php, android-studio, xampp

I try to upload a picture to a server via android studio app. The upload via http to different servers works, but when i try to use an own server (my notebook), the uploaded picture has an empty name and 0byte. I created my server with XAMPP.
My java code in android studio is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final String SERVER_ADRESS = "MY_IP_ADRESS";

    ImageView imageToUpload, downloadedImage;
    Button bUploadImage, bDownloadImage;
    EditText uploadImageName, downloadImageName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageToUpload = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageToUpload);
        downloadedImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.downloadedImage);

        bUploadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bUploadImage);
        bDownloadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDownloadImage);

        uploadImageName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUploadName);
        downloadImageName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDownloadName);

        imageToUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
        bUploadImage.setOnClickListener(this);
        bDownloadImage.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.imageToUpload:
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                break;

            case R.id.bUploadImage:
                Bitmap image = ((BitmapDrawable) imageToUpload.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                new UploadImage(image, uploadImageName.getText().toString()).execute();
                break;

            case R.id.bDownloadImage:

                break;

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void  onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            imageToUpload.setImageURI(selectedImage);

        }
    }


    private class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{


        Bitmap image;
        String name;

        public UploadImage(Bitmap image, String name){
            this.image = image;
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
            String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", encodedImage));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));

            HttpParams httpRequestParams = getHttpRequestParams();

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://MY_IP_ADRESS/SavePicture.php");


            try {
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
                client.execute(post);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    private HttpParams getHttpRequestParams(){
        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, 100 * 30);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, 100 * 30);
        return httpRequestParams;

    }


}
```

The SavePicture.php is:

```
<?php

        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $image = $_POST["image"];

        $decodedImage = base64_decode("$image");
        file_put_contents("pictures/" . $name . ".JPG", $decodedImage);
?>
```

I don´t know what the problem is... with other servers it works fine. And the upload to my server works, but ,as i wrote, only with 0 bytes and emty name.

Thank you for help!!
Kind regards
Martin

Comment: could you try adding an **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** content type to your request

Comment: Thank you! I will try it. It didn't work with the wifi of my girlfriend, but when I start the server at home with my ofn wifi everything works. Don't know why :) but I will also try it with your idea! Thanks and have a good day!